# How to create barcode image with interleaved2of5 without displaying its text

Tags: java, itext

I am using itext pdf jars to generate the barcode image using inter2of5.

How can I display barcode image only and not display the text (barcode value)?

Below method display the image with the text underneath the barcode..please advise

```
//Creates Audit barcode image without the message(barcode number).
        BarcodeInter25 audBarcode = new BarcodeInter25();
        audBarcode.setCode(123456789);

        Color black = new Color(0, 0, 0);
        Color white = new Color(255, 255, 255);
        Image audBarcodeImg = Image.getInstance(audBarcode.createImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null));
        audBarcodeImg.setRotationDegrees(-90);
        audBarcodeImg.setAbsolutePosition(18, 410);
        samplePdfDoc.add(123456789);
        audBarcode.setStartStopText(false);
```

Comment: Provide some more code.

Comment: Where is the variable `cb` declared?

Comment: can you try `audBarcode.setAltText("")`? Also `samplePdfDoc.add(123456789)` looks odd

Comment: i tried using the method createAWTmage instead of createImageWithBarcode and it returned the barcode with no text....thank all for ur help

Answer (score 1):

First two observations:

1. You didn't copy/paste code that compiles. For instance: the `setCode()` needs a `String` not an `int`. You never add the barcode to `samplePdfDoc` and you can't add an `int` to `samplePdfDoc`...
2. You are using an obsolete version of iText. That's a bad idea. See http://itextpdf.com/salesfaq for more info.

Now the solution: as documented in my [book](http://itextpdf.com/book), you can remove the text by setting the font to `null`. I've taken your code and turned it into something that makes more sense:

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
document.open();
PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
BarcodeInter25 audBarcode = new BarcodeInter25();
audBarcode.setCode("0123456789");
audBarcode.setStartStopText(false); 
audBarcode.setFont(null);
Image audBarcodeImg = Image.getInstance(audBarcode.createImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null));
audBarcodeImg.setRotationDegrees(-90);
audBarcodeImg.setAbsolutePosition(18, 410);
document.add(audBarcodeImg);
document.close();
```

Now the code compiles, executes and shows the barcode without text. Please consider reading the documentation, and more importantly: please upgrade to the latest iText version as you're using a version that has been declared dead years ago.